# firebase get key of last node created

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the key of the last node I have just pushed to on firebase but my code keeps erroring

```
constructor (props) {
super(props)
this.cartFirebase = firebaseApp.database().ref('carts')


}

  componentDidMount () {
    this.cartFirebase.child(DeviceInfo.getUniqueID() + '/items').push({
      item: this.props.data.name,
      qty: 1
    })
    this.cartFirebase.limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot)
    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen added the error

Comment: As the error message says `limit()` is not a function. Are you looking for `limitToFirst()` or `limitToLast()`?

Comment: limit to last, wanted to get the most recent node that has been created

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `limitToLast` function.

```
this.cartFirebase.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {

     var snap = childSnapshot.val();

});
```