# Get the last saved item in FireBase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am developing a mobile app with ionic 3 that consumes API from a ASP.NET Web APi project , am using Token based Auth to authenticate  users , i can get the token and save it in a FireBase database but everytime the user logs in a new token get saved to the Database so how can I get the last saved item from FireBase Db???

Comment: You can possibly do this using a query with `limitToLast` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117889/3055401

Comment: I will give it a try . :) thank you