# Firebase - Getting first value of last child Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Attempting to read the Temp value of the last child in the following Firebase structure, however unable to read the child value.

Firebase Database Structure below:
[image]

Attempted code;

```
//GET last child and return val for temperature;
var lastChild_Light = firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child("av")
  .child("data")
  .child("01230C3DB6717F1DFE")
  .limitToLast(1)
  .child("Temp");
lastChild_Light.on("value", function(lastdatasnap) {
  document.getElementById("lastTemp").innerText = lastdatasnap.val();
});
```

The idea is for the user to see the latest temp value, once they land on webpage.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking `Javascript` solution the following would work

```
firebase.database().ref('io/av/data/01230C3DB6717F1DFE/').limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

    console.log(snapshot.val());      // gives key and value pair -  {Temp: "35.43"}

    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      console.log(child.val());       //  gives value of key

   });

});
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117889/9493145)  could be of more help.